# Compile error type conversion return type Promise<any[]> Async

Tags: typescript

I have this async function:

```
async getItems() : Promise<any[]> {}
```

that fetches some data. Call of the function on Table component:

```
dataSource={this.props.itemsStore.getItems()}
```

Error message:

```
Type 'Promise<any[]>' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 28 more.
```

Comment: Is that error coming from the *implementation* of `getItems`? Give a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

getItems() is returning a promise. If you want to get the value out of that promise, you have to use `await` since you are using async on your function.

So try this:

```
dataSource = await this.props.itemsStore.getItems();
```

EDIT

Another way to get the value out of the promise in TypeScript is like this:

```
this.props.itemsStore.getItems().then(items => dataSource = items);
```

Comment: I tried that before but that produced error: 'await' expressions are only allowed within async functions and at the top levels of modules. for me.

Comment: .then(res => res.json()) .then((result)=>{}), so i also I have fetch with these two promises inside getItems, is it possible type declaration has to be added to those arguments?